# Want to append the added items to the file but it loops and write for previous items

Tags: java

This is my write file function

```java
public static void write() {
    try {
        PrintWriter a = new PrintWriter("item.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < allItem.size();i++) {
            ItemList c = allItem.get(i);
            a.println(c.name);
            a.println(c.category);
            a.println(c.price);
            a.println();
        }
        a.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in write(Item) ...");
    }
}
```

This is my add function. My text file will loop and write previous items in text file like chicken chop, spaghetti. And I add a nasi lemak. It will be like chicken chop, spaghetti, chicken chop, spaghetti, nasi lemak.

```java
String cc1 = tf1.getText();
Customer found = Info.checkUserName(cc1);
String b = y.getSelectedItem();
if (found == null) {
    if (b.equals("Others")) {
        String g = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New Food Category");
        if (category.equals(g)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(x, "Category exists");
        } else {
            category.add(g);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(x, "Food category added successfully!");
        }
    }
    double d = Double.parseDouble(tf4.getText());
    Item.allItem.add(new ItemList(cc1, b, d));
    Item.write();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(x, "Items added successfully!");
    x.setVisible(false);
    Assignment.no2.y.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: If you only want to write the last item, you don't need the `for` loop. Just select the last one like this: `ItemList c = allItem.get(allItem.size() - 1);` and remove the `for` loop.

Comment: Please check your question follows [ask]